# Unresolved external 'WSADuplicateSocketW' link error

Tags: c++builder

I have problem with WSADuplicateSocket function linking. Ws2_32.lib is present, library path is set correctly. Is WSADuplicateSocket suported for Windows 7? it's possible pass socket to child process without WSADuplicateSocket?

IDE: C++Builder XE5, OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is WSADuplicateSocket suported for Windows 7?

Yes.

But this is not a Windows 7 issue.  This is an IDE/project issue.  Either your copy of `ws2_32.lib` in the `$(BDS)\lib\win32\release\psdk` and/or `$(BDS)\lib\win32\release` folder (whichever one your project is linking to) does not contain a symbol for `WSADuplicateSocketW`, or you are not actually linking `ws2_32.lib` into your project to begin with.  Either of those would cause the linker to complain.  My guess is on the latter.

I checked those `.lib` files in XE2 and XE5 and the `WSADuplicateSocketW` symbol does exist in both versions.  So make sure you are actually linking to `ws2_32.lib` and do not have a bad/corrupt installation.  If you need to, you can use the command-line `IMPLIB.EXE` tool to create a new `ws2_32.lib` file from `ws2_32.dll` in your Windows folder.

> it's possible pass socket to child process without WSADuplicateSocket?

No.

Comment: ws2_32.dll and ws2_32.lib are damaged. Issue is fixed by copy ws2_32.dll from any PC and create ws2_32.lib.